# Taking some variables or objects from other class

Tags: java

how can I invoke a constructor which is below from main class

```
public Point(Point m){
    this.x = m.x;
    this.y = m.y;
}
```

I want to call this constructor from main method and I dont know how to I can do that.

Comment: How do you invoke a constructor?

Comment: ?? The constructor is called when you create the object

Comment: `new Point(anotherPoint)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially what you have there is a copy constructor, so you need to already have an instance of `Point` lying around to use it. Putting reflection aside, this means that you need another constructor, perhaps one that takes the coordinates directly:

```
public Point(int x, int y) {  // or doubles, whichever type you're using
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

Now, you can do:

```
Point p1 = new Point(5, 7);  // calls above constructor

Point copy = new Point(p1);  // calls your constructor
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
Point p = new Point(new Point(1, 2));// considering that there is a constructor in Point class taking (int x, int y) parameters.
```

Answer (score 0):

not possible unless you add another Point constructor which has not a Point as parameter.
After providing another Constructor you could do something like this:

```
public class Starter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point p = new Point(3,5);
    }

}
```

Comment: ı add three constructors